# Average True Range and Exponential Moving Average Functions on PandasDataSeries needed

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

I am stuck while calculating Average True Range[ATR] of a Series.
        ATR is basically a Exp Movin Avg of TrueRange[TR]

```
 TR is nothing but MAX of -
       Method 1: Current High less the current Low
       Method 2: Current High less the previous Close (absolute value)
       Method 3: Current Low less the previous Close (absolute value)
```

In Pandas we dont have an inbuilt EMA function. Rather we have EWMA which is a weighted moving average.

If someone helps to calculate EMA that also will be good enough

```
      def ATR(df,n):
          df['H-L']=abs(df['High']-df['Low'])
          df['H-PC']=abs(df['High']-df['Close'].shift(1))
          df['L-PC']=abs(df['Low']-df['Close'].shift(1))
          df['TR']=df[['H-L','H-PC','L-PC']].max(axis=1)
          df['ATR_' + str(n)] =pd.ewma(df['TR'], span = n, min_periods = n)
          return df
```

The above code doesnt give error but it also doesnt give correct values either. I compared it with manually calculating ATR values on same dataseries in excel and values were different

```
           ATR excel formula-
             Current ATR = [(Prior ATR x 13) + Current TR] / 14

             - Multiply the previous 14-day ATR by 13.
             - Add the most recent day's TR value.
             - Divide the total by 14
```

This is the dataseries I used as a sample

```
           start='2016-1-1'
           end='2016-10-30'
           auro=web.DataReader('AUROPHARMA.NS','yahoo',start,end)
```

Comment: How to calculate ATR is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821392/python-atr-calculation/68018425#68018425

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use ewma
See here: An exponential moving average (EMA) is a type of moving average that is similar to a simple moving average, except that more weight is given to the latest data.

Read more: Exponential Moving Average (EMA) http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ema.asp#ixzz4ishZbOGx

I dont think your excel formula is right... Here is a manual way to calculate ema in python

```
def exponential_average(values, window):
    weights = np.exp(np.linspace(-1.,0.,window))
    weights /= weights.sum()

    a = np.convolve(values, weights) [:len(values)]
    a[:window]=a[window]
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

[scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) could help you.

```
scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1,zi=None)
```

The filter function is implemented as a direct II transposed structure. This means that the filter implements:

```
a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M]
                      - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]
```

If we normalize the above formula, we obtain the following one:

```
y[n] = b'[0]*x[n] + b'[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b'[M]*x[n-M]
                  - a'[1]*y[n-1] + ... + a'[N]*y[n-N]
```

where `b'[i] = b[i]/a[0], i = 0,1,...,M; a'[j] = a[j]/a[0],j = 1,2,...,N` 
and `a'[0] = 1`

Exponential Moving Average formula:

```
y[n] = alpha*x[n] + (1-alpha)*y[n-1]
```

So to apply scipy.signal.lfilter, by the formula above we can set a and b as below:

```
a[0] = 1, a[1] = -(1-alpha)
b[0] = alpha
```

My implementation is as below, hope it to help you.

```
def ema(values, window_size):
    alpha = 2./ (window_size + 1)
    a = np.array([1, alpha - 1.])
    b = np.array([alpha])
    zi = sig.lfilter_zi(b, a)
    y, _ = sig.lfilter(b, a, values, zi=zi)
    return y
```