# Calculate Average True Range for range breakout in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

[image]

I have a sheet like this. I have calculated following things:-

1. Current High - Current Low
2. abs(Current High - Previous Close)
3. abs(Current Low - Previous Close)
   Then I have also calculated True Range. over different symbols. Now I need to calculate Average True Range over 10 days. How should I do that in python pandas?

Comment: Please take a look at [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Please have a look to the answer for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821392/python-atr-calculation/68018425#68018425